# Setting Basic auth credentials to HttpRequestBase does not work

Tags: java, basic-authentication

```
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
String encoding = new String(Base64.encodeBase64((USERNAME+":"+PASSWORD).getBytes()));  
request.addHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + encoding);
```

I set the username and password to basic auth as provided in samny examples. But still i dont get the correct encoded string. Even i tried it with external tools the encoded string does nto match the encoded strings created by other tools like (Chrome plugin : AdvancedRestClient). Any idea whats wrong in this code ?

PS: If i set the string generated from somewhere else driectly then it works. So the problem should be in encoding

Comment: specify `UTF-8` encoding in `getBytes()`.

Comment: thankx.. but i was setting wrong username and password.

Comment: The question was asked without debugging much. Found out its not a problem in code

Comment: ok, in other cases make sure that client and server use the same character encoding to process base64 encoded string.